# Want to splice an element from an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to splice an item from an array, my array is like,

```
array=[{'PatientID':545, 'Name':jey, 'ref': d},
       {'PatientID':544, 'Name':tay, 'ref': dj},
       .... ]
```

I wrote a code for splicing, but it does'nt work,
`Uncaught TypeError: item.PatientID.indexOf is not a function`
this error is occured

```
remove(id){
    var index = array.map(item=>{(item.PatientID).indexOf(id)})
....
}
```

How to resolve my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the `index` based on the `id`

```
const findIndex = id => array.findIndex(i => i.id === id)

const index = findIndex('545')
```

To remove an item based on the id

```
const deleteItem = id =>{
    return array.filter(i => i.id !== id)
}

const newArray = deleteItem(545)
```

Mutating the array

```
const deleteItem = id =>{
    const index = array.indexOf(i => i.id === id)
    array.splice(index, 1)
}
```